# Transposing a SQL Server Table without aggregating

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table which I'd like to transpose, i.e. switch the rows and columns.

The original table looks like this:

```
empname     empqual     emprank    empexp
Lily        MASTERS        1         9       
Sasha       UNIVERSITY     1         9
Harry       UNIVERSITY     1         9
Angela      MASTERS        4        10
Joyce       UNIVERSITY     5        11
```

Please note that the row data is dynamic and the above table is just to demonstrate the table schema.

**EDIT:** I'd like to modify the above table so that it looks like this:

```
DETAILS    Column1     Column2     Column3    Column4     Column5
empname     Lily       Sasha        Harry      Angela      Joyce
empqual    MASTERS    UNIVERSITY  UNIVERSITY  MASTERS    UNIVERSITY
emprank       1           1          1          4           5
empexp        9           9          9          10          11
```

I have looked through several online examples. The `PIVOT` function seems to be the most commonly-used function when tables are transposed, but since the operation I require doesn't involve any aggregations, unlike most other examples, I do not know how to do this. Apologies if this question is redundant and a possible answer already exists elsewhere.

Comment: Use `PIVOT` and select an arbitrary aggregate (`MIN` or `MAX` are usually preferred). You may know that your table will only contain one row for each combination, but SQL Server can't construct a plan that assumes that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Could you possibly give me the entire SQL construct for this? I'm unable to use `PIVOT` as the row data is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check at this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86e0c/24)

**EDIT**

I made it dynamic...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 'Column' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By empname))
            FROM Table1 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = '
SELECT 1 as OrderBy,
       * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By empname)) AS Columns, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,empname) as e, 
    ''empname'' AS Details
    FROM Table1 
) p
PIVOT
(
  MAX (e)
  FOR Columns IN
( 
  ' + @cols + ' )
) as pvt


UNION

SELECT 2 as OrderBy,
       * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By empname)) AS Columns, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,empqual) as e, 
    ''empqual'' AS Details
    FROM Table1 
) p
PIVOT
(
  MAX (e)
  FOR Columns IN
( 
 ' + @cols + ' )
) as pvt

UNION

SELECT 3 as OrderBy,
       * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By empname)) AS Columns, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,emprank) as e, 
    ''emprank'' AS Details
    FROM Table1 
) p
PIVOT
(
   MAX (e)
   FOR Columns IN
( 
  ' + @cols + ' )
) as pvt

UNION 

SELECT 4 as OrderBy,
       * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ''Column'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Row_Number() OVER (Order By empname)) AS Columns, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,empexp) as e, 
    ''empexp'' AS Details
    FROM Table1 
) p
PIVOT
(
  MAX (e)
  FOR Columns IN
( 
  ' + @cols + ' )
) as pvt

order by OrderBy'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

Giannis

Comment: This is excellent, though I'm afraid I didn't make it clear that the 'empname's themselves shouldn't be the column headers of the new table. Instead, it would be better if they were 'Column1', 'Column2' etc, corresponding to each employee, and the 'empname's should be values underneath those column headers, just like the attributes. I've attempted to edit your code, but the `PIVOT` seems to be fetching data according to the values stored in `@cols`, which are the 'empname's. Changing `@cols` to 'Column1', 'Column2' etc. makes all the rows null.

Comment: I have now edited the modified table in the original post so that it matches my requirements.

Comment: Do take a look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5031/13 I have simply modified your code so that the initial table has the column names as well, and the `@cols` variable is modified to contain the column names instead of the 'empname's. However, my incoming data is unlikely to contain the column names. Therefore, could you possibly modify the code so that the column names are appended to the table after the data has been inserted?

Comment: Ok, i changed my code so you won't have to add the new column.

Answer (score 0):

This query works for your sample data:

```
declare @t table(
    empname varchar(20) not null,
    empqual varchar(20) not null,
    emprank int not null,
    empexp int not null
)
insert into @t(empname,empqual,emprank,empexp) values
('Lily','MASTERS',1,9),    
('Sasha','UNIVERSITY',1,9),
('Harry','UNIVERSITY',1,9),
('Angela','MASTERS',4,10),
('Joyce','UNIVERSITY',5,11)

select *
from (select empname,empqual,CONVERT(varchar(20),emprank) as emprank,CONVERT(varchar(20),empexp) as empexp from @t) t
unpivot (value FOR measure in (empqual,emprank,empexp)) as unpvt
pivot (MAX(value) for empname in (Lily,Sasha,Harry,Angela,Joyce)) pvt
order by
    CASE measure WHEN 'empqual' THEN 0
                WHEN 'emprank' THEN 1
                WHEN 'empexp' THEN 2
                END
```

Result:

```
measure      Lily                 Sasha                Harry                Angela               Joyce
------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
empqual      MASTERS              UNIVERSITY           UNIVERSITY           MASTERS              UNIVERSITY
emprank      1                    1                    1                    4                    5
empexp       9                    9                    9                    10                   11
```

If your comment about "row data is dynamic" means that you have an unknown list of names, then you'll need to write a query that obtains the list of names first, and then builds the above query using that list of names in the `PIVOT` section.

A simple search for "dynamic pivot" should find plenty of examples of doing so.